# Make one column in price table stick out with bootstrap (3d effect)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to create a price table like this in bootstrap https://d85wutc1n854v.cloudfront.net/live/products/600x375/WB0PF9PH7.png?v=1.0 and as you can see is there a 3d effect on column number 3 (pro). How do I make that 3d effect?

This is my code now with four flat columns. No extra css.

```
<section class="container show-source">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="panel panel-info">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h3 class="text-center">Gratis testperiod</h3></div>
                <div class="panel-body text-center">
                    <p class="lead" style="font-size:40px"><strong>$15</strong></p>
                </div>
                <ul class="list-group list-group-flush text-center">
                    <li class="list-group-item"><i class="icon-ok text-danger"></i> Personal use</li>
                    <li class="list-group-item"><i class="icon-ok text-danger"></i> Unlimited projects</li>
                    <li class="list-group-item"><i class="icon-ok text-danger"></i> 27/7 support</li>
                </ul>
                <div class="panel-footer">
                    <a class="btn btn-lg btn-block btn-danger" href="#">BUY NOW!</a>
                </div>
                <!--/panel-footer-->
            </div>
            <!--/panel-->
        </div>
        <!--/col-->
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="panel panel-info">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h3 class="text-center">Pro Plan</h3></div>
                <div class="panel-body text-center">
                    <p class="lead" style="font-size:40px"><strong>$10</strong></p>
                </div>
                <ul class="list-group list-group-flush text-center">
                    <li class="list-group-item"><i class="icon-ok text-danger"></i> Personal use</li>
                    <li class="list-group-item"><i class="icon-ok text-danger"></i> Unlimited projects</li>
                    <li class="list-group-item"><i class="icon-ok text-danger"></i> 27/7 support</li>
                </ul>
                <div class="panel-footer">
                    <a class="btn btn-lg btn-block btn-danger" href="#">BUY NOW!</a>
                </div>
                <!--/panel-footer-->
            </div>
            <!--/panel-->
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="panel panel-info">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h3 class="text-center">Pro Plan</h3></div>
                <div class="panel-body text-center">
                    <p class="lead" style="font-size:40px"><strong>$10</strong></p>
                </div>
                <ul class="list-group list-group-flush text-center">
                    <li class="list-group-item"><i class="icon-ok text-danger"></i> Personal use</li>
                    <li class="list-group-item"><i class="icon-ok text-danger"></i> Unlimited projects</li>
                    <li class="list-group-item"><i class="icon-ok text-danger"></i> 27/7 support</li>
                </ul>
                <div class="panel-footer">
                    <a class="btn btn-lg btn-block btn-danger" href="#">BUY NOW!</a>
                </div>
                <!--/panel-footer-->
            </div>
            <!--/panel-->
        </div>
        <!--/col-->
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="panel panel-info">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h3 class="text-center">Free Plan</h3></div>
                <div class="panel-body text-center">
                    <p class="lead" style="font-size:40px"><strong>$0</strong></p>
                </div>
                <ul class="list-group list-group-flush text-center">
                    <li class="list-group-item"><i class="icon-ok text-danger"></i> Personal use</li>
                    <li class="list-group-item"><i class="icon-ok text-danger"></i> Unlimited projects</li>
                    <li class="list-group-item"><i class="icon-ok text-danger"></i> 27/7 support</li>
                </ul>
                <div class="panel-footer">
                    <a class="btn btn-lg btn-block btn-danger" href="#">BUY NOW!</a>
                </div>
                <!--/panel-footer-->
            </div>
            <!--/panel-->
        </div>
        <!--/col-->
    </div>
    <!--/row-->
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to scale it `width` and `height` as in example, and add a `box-shadow`

for example this

```
box-shadow: 10px 10px 52px 13px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
```

Answer (score 0):

Buy this for $5, it has all the code you need and seems to be where the image came from.

https://wrapbootstrap.com/theme/responsive-pricing-tables-WB0PF9PH7

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quite simple JSFiddle that may help you: https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/23628/

There are three major components of the JSFiddle:

1. Make the gutter of Bootstrap grid to 0: adding the following class `.no-gutter` along with the class `.row`

   ```
   .no-gutter > [class*='col-'] {
       padding-right:0;
       padding-left:0;
   }
   ```
2. `zoom` the column you want to pop up
3. Set the `box-shadow`

   For step 2 and step 3, I set up an id for the column i want to pop up as follows:

   ```
   #pop {
       zoom: 1.1;
       z-index: 100;
       top: -20px;
       -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
       -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
       box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
   }
   ```

Hope this may help you!

Comment: Also, you can make the price table more interactive by setting the pop-up effect as a hove effect of those pricing columns.

Answer (score 0):

```
<body>
<div id="main-content">
     <div class="container-fluid">
         <div class="row-fluid">
             <div class="span12">
                 <div class="widget black">

                     <div class="widget-body">

                         <div class="row-fluid">
                             <div class="span3">
                                 <div class="pricing-table terques">
                                     <div class="pricing-head">
                                         <h3> Micro </h3>
                                         <h4>
                                             <span class="note">$</span>20 <span>Per Month</span></h4>
                                     </div>
                                     <ul>
                                         <li><strong>Free</strong> setup</li>
                                         <li><strong>1</strong> Website</li>
                                         <li><strong>2</strong> Projects</li>
                                         <li><strong>1GB</strong> Storage</li>
                                         <li><strong>$0</strong> Google Adwords Credit</li>
                                     </ul>
                                     <div class="price-actions">
                                         <a href="javascript:;" class="btn">Purchase Now</a>
                                     </div>
                                 </div>
                             </div>
                             <div class="spance10 visible-phone"></div>
                             <div class="span3">
                                 <div class="pricing-table red">
                                     <div class="pricing-head">
                                         <h3> Starter </h3>
                                         <h4>
                                             <span class="note">$</span>30 <span>Per Month</span></h4>
                                     </div>
                                     <ul>
                                         <li><strong>Free</strong> setup</li>
                                         <li><strong>5</strong> Website</li>
                                         <li><strong>10</strong> Projects</li>
                                         <li><strong>15GB</strong> Storage</li>
                                         <li><strong>$30</strong> Google Adwords Credit</li>
                                     </ul>
                                     <div class="price-actions">
                                         <a href="javascript:;" class="btn">Purchase Now</a>
                                     </div>
                                 </div>
                             </div>
                             <div class="spance10 visible-phone"></div>
                             <div class="span3">
                                 <div class="pricing-table green most-popular">
                                     <div class="pricing-head ">
                                         <h3> Business </h3>
                                         <h4>
                                             <span class="note">$</span>60 <span>Per Month</span></h4>
                                     </div>
                                     <ul>
                                         <li><strong>Free</strong> setup</li>
                                         <li><strong>10</strong> Website</li>
                                         <li><strong>20</strong> Projects</li>
                                         <li><strong>Unlimited</strong> Storage</li>
                                         <li><strong>$50</strong> Google Adwords Credit</li>
                                     </ul>
                                     <div class="price-actions">
                                         <a href="javascript:;" class="btn">Purchase Now</a>
                                     </div>
                                 </div>
                             </div>
                             <div class="spance10 visible-phone"></div>
                             <div class="span3">
                                 <div class="pricing-table purple">
                                     <div class="pricing-head">
                                         <h3> Enterprise </h3>
                                         <h4>
                                             <span class="note">$</span>120 <span>Per Month</span></h4>
                                     </div>
                                     <ul>
                                         <li><strong>Free</strong> setup</li>
                                         <li><strong>20</strong> Website</li>
                                         <li><strong>30</strong> Projects</li>
                                         <li><strong>Unlimited</strong> Storage</li>
                                         <li><strong>$100</strong> Google Adwords Credit</li>
                                     </ul>
                                     <div class="price-actions">
                                         <a href="javascript:;" class="btn">Purchase Now</a>
                                     </div>
                                 </div>
                             </div>
                         </div>
                     </div>
                 </div>
             </div>
         </div>
     </div>
 </div>
```

and head use,

```
<head>
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="css/bootstrap-fileupload.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="css/style-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="css/style-default.css" rel="stylesheet" id="style_color" />
</head>
```

create css folder and save the above mentioned css pages..

[Bootstrap v2.3.1](http://bootstrapdocs.com/v2.3.1/docs/) and try it

Comment: how to import css file in stackoverflow ?